# Four long blinks, four short blinks

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues

Have a brand new NEEGO Raspberry Pi 4 kit. 32 GB micro SD, with NOOBS supposedly installed.

Start it up, I get four long blinks of the green LED, followed by four short blinks.

OK, I have a Pi 3B, try interchanging parts.

The Pi 3B, with the SD from the kit installed, boots into Raspbian from two years ago, instead of NOOBS as expected.

The Pi 4 from the kit boots fine from the SD that belongs to the Pi 3B.

Use the Pi 3B to upgrade the SD from the kit. All goes well, but, the SD from the kit still won't boot the Pi 4: it still does four long blinks, four short blinks.

So, any ideas on how to get the SD from the kit to work with the kit?

Edit:

I'm working remotely with a student on this project, and we're setting up parallel systems on opposite coasts. He had the same problem, but was able to make a bootable system using Raspberry Pi Imager. Thanks to overnight delivery of a card interface, I was able to follow his lead. So the problem is solved.

The puzzle still remains, though, why didn't it work out of the box? Having poked a bit more at the card, I think part of the answer is that it really was a NOOBS card that wasn't properly set up for a Pi 4. It had the partition layout of a NOOBS card. But then, why did it boot directly into Raspberry Pi OS on a Pi 3, and why did an older card with a NOOBS layout and an identical OS boot on the Pi 4?

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/led_blink_warnings.md) - it states that `4  4  Unsupported board type` - personally, if the SD card from "the kit" has NOOBS on it, erase it and put a real operating system on it - NOOBS is effectively unsupported

Comment: @JaromandaX As I said above, I already put an up to date Raspberry Pi OS on the SD. Still won't boot on the Pi 4.

Comment: No you didn't put Raspberry Pi OS on the card. This is impossible without a SD Card reader (on the Pi or anything else).

Comment: "I already put an up to date Raspberry Pi OS on the SD" - no, you didn't say that at all

Comment: @JaromandaX The new SD boots on a Pi 3. The OS on the new SD is identical to the OS on the old SD that I normally use on the Pi 3. The old SD boots on the Pi 4. Two cards, identical OS's, one boots on both boards, the other boots on one. See comment below for the (minor) differences in the configuration in `/boot`.

Answer (score 0):

The flashes indicate the problem.

```
Long Short status
0   3   Generic failure to boot
0   4   start*.elf not found
0   7   Kernel image not found
0   8   SDRAM failure
0   9   Insufficient SDRAM
0   10  In HALT state
2   1   Partition not FAT
2   2   Failed to read from partition
2   3   Extended partition not FAT
2   4   File signature/hash mismatch - Pi 4
3   1   SPI EEPROM error - Pi 4
3   2   SPI EEPROM is write protected - Pi 4
3   3   I2C error - Pi 4
4   4   Unsupported board type
4   5   Fatal firmware error
4   6   Power failure type A
4   7   Power failure type B
```

That means: unsupported board type. This means that the kit vendor has not tested that the system worked before it was shipped. The OS version on the SD card is too old for your Pi.

Things to do:

- Download the latest version of Raspian
- Put it on the SD card and boot
- write a bad review about the kit-provider :-)

Do not do an upgrade on the Pi, download the newest version and put that on the SD card. There is a difference in the result.

Once the Pi 4 is booted, look at `/proc/cpuinfo`. You will probably see it is revision 1.4.

---EDIT---

Because the OP is restricted in the SD-card readers, a possible way out would be the following:

- On the Pi3 with the Pi3-card: `cp -rp /boot /some/usbstick`
- (optional) On the Pi3 with the kit-card: verify that there are indeed different m5sums on the usbstick and the `/boot`-partition.
- On the Pi3 with the kit card: `cp -rp /some/usbstick/boot/* /boot`
- put in the kit-card in the kit-Pi
- try to boot the kit-pi from the kit-card
- `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`
- As this is a new install, I would also  `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Except **as I said above**, the Pi 4 works with the SD card from my Pi 3. I have, using my Pi 3, upgraded to **the same OS** that the working card has on the card that doesn't work on the Pi 4. That card works on the Pi 3, but not on the Pi 4. Same OS, different result. Files in /boot are identical except for date stamps and my custom setting of lcd_rotate for the Pi 3. So, I have two cards with the *same os*. Both work on my Pi 3. Only one works on my new Pi 4.

Comment: Did you `dd` the card or did you insert the card in the pi3 and ran `apt update; apt upgrade`? If the latter, please read my answer again.

Comment: I **can't** `dd` the card. The only computers I have with SD card slots are Raspberry Pi's. And, anyway, the cards aren't the same size (the one that came with the kit is smaller). How is it that one card upgraded by `apt update; apt upgrade` on a Pi 3 works on the Pi 4, while a different card given the same treatment doesn't? What, *exactly*, do you expect `dd` to do differently? Is there something hidden outside the filesystems that needs patching?

Comment: I would not expect the files in the `/boot` partition to be identical between your two cards. Have you compared them? Do all the files have the same `md5sum` (that is different from having the same size)? Did you check? Anyway: the OS on the kit's SD card does not support the Pi4. That is the message. You can shuffle it around how you like, but unless you put in the newest version of the OS, it ain't gonna work. See the addition of my answer.

Comment: I copied the two `/boot` dirs to a USB drive with `cp -aR` and compared the dirs with 'diff -r' on a third machine. Three files differ:  `config.txt` (screen rotation), `issue.txt` (date and hash), and `os_config.json` (release_date). I don't believe any of these could possibly affect the early stages of boot. No binary files differ. So, I am thoroughly perplexed that one card boots on the Pi 4, while the other doesn't.